# How do I get F11 and F12 to behave like normal function keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, preferences

I have a 2013 MacBook Pro Retina 15" and I'm trying to set the function keys to perform as normal function keys.  So I want the behaviour to be inverted from the standard behaviour where I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> to get the keys to work normally.  I've enabled the setting in Preferences as shown below.

[image: Preferences Pane]

This works fine for all function keys except <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> both have the expected behaviour of adjusting the volume now, but when I press <kbd>F11</kbd> by itself it enters Expose and when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> by itself it launches Dashboard.

How can I get my <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys to just behave like normal function keys?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Well I actually just figured this out.  In Preferences under Mission Control there were two options set to use the <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> keys.  I set these to '-' and that fixed the issue.  The options that were set to use these function keys are highlighted in the screenshot below.

[image: Mission Control Prefpane]

2024 Note: MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1 this config option has moved: *System Settings →  Desktop & Dock →  Keyboard and Mouse Shortcut →  Show Desktop*

Comment: In OS X 10.9 Mavericks (and possibly earlier too), the same setting can *also* be changed from Keyboard, Shortcuts, in the Mission Control section there.

Comment: cono I'm still having orbs with the f11 and f12. when I changed the show desktop and show dashboard to blank, the buttons moved the screen to dashboard, but the volume still doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  If you've already done what I did in this answer then you must have a separate issue.  It might be worth asking another question

Comment: This is making life working remotely from my Apple machines so much better!

Comment: Very very useful. Now I am able to boot into PXE again over ilo!

Comment: I love F11 for expose... however I'd like it not to do this *only when using VS Code*.